# Spring batch error tolerance

Tags: spring-batch

I'm trying to import city data from a csv file, some data may be duplicated which invoke conflict error `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "city__unique_idx"
  Detail: Key (country, city_name, latitude, longitude)=(231, Monticello, 30.5450000000000017, -83.8703000000000003) already exists.
2018-03-13 14:34:03.607 ERROR 13275 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step cityStep1 in job importCityJob`. I want to know how to ignore this error and keep the job running because it currently exits immediately.

Writer:

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<City> cityWriter(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    JpaItemWriter<City> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);
    return writer;
}
```

Here is my job method:

```
@Bean
public Step cityStep1(ItemWriter<City> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("cityStep1").<City, City>chunk(10).reader(cityReader())
            .processor(cityProcessor()).writer(writer).build();
}

@Bean
public Job importHotelJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step cityStep) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importCityJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .next(cityStep1)
            .build();
```

Thanks.

**Edit1:**

After I applied `faultTolerant()`

```
@Bean
public Step cityStep1(ItemWriter<City> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("cityStep1").<City, City>chunk(50).reader(cityReader())
            .processor(cityProcessor()).writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(ConflictException.class)
            .skip(ConstraintViolationException.class)
            .noRetry(ConflictException.class)
            .noRetry(ConstraintViolationException.class)
            .skipLimit(150)
            .build();
```

I still get error:

```
2018-03-14 15:49:40.047 ERROR 26613 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "city__unique_idx"
  Detail: Key (country, city_name, latitude, longitude)=(231, Monticello, 30.5450000000000017, -83.8703000000000003) already exists.
2018-03-14 15:49:40.161 ERROR 26613 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step cityStep1 in job importCityJob
org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: That error means that your threshold of `150` for bad records is breached.

Comment: @SabirKhan the threshold does not affect the error, it appears at same record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your step fault tolerant for specific exceptions.

```
@Bean
public Step cityStep1(ItemWriter<City> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("cityStep1")
                .<City,City>chunk(10)
                .reader(cityReader())
                .processor(cityProcessor())
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(YourException.class)
                .noRetry(YourException.class)
                .noRollback(YourException.class)
                .skipLimit(10)
                .build();
}
```

You haven't listed your writer or exception that you received so you can put that exception in place of `YourException`.

`noRetry` , `noRollBack` have been put to alter default Spring Batch behavior in case of skipping as spring batch roll backs transaction for whole chunk & then reprocesses item bu item. If you are OK with that way, you can remove these parts from your step definition.

Comment: I tried this way already, it gave me some exhausting error (sorry I can't remember the error name).

Comment: If I understand right, this command will ignore all chunk once encounter an exception. If I want to just ignore the single item that produces error, what should I do? If I remove noRollback, it will examine items in the error chunk, but what happens if it iterates again to that single error item, does it rollback to that item also or just ignore it when it's the second time?

Comment: When Spring Batch goes to process items one by one for retry , it will find problematic item & skip it - that is whole point of iterating for second time.

Comment: What do you mean by unskippable ?