# Spring Data JPA - escape accent french character (é, à, è, û..)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA method name query to do SQL query, such as `findByNameContains(String name)` to find all entities whose name contains a given string. But it only applies to exact characters. I'd like to know if a user enters `é`, how to return all entities whose name contain character `é` and its base character `e`. Thanks.

Comment: do you have special characters in the database, or just from the input of the user?

Comment: beside what rdbms you are using?

Comment: Yes, I want English character and its variants become interchangeable during searching. I have `Montreal` and `Montréal` in my DB, I want to return both names when user enter `Montreal` or `Montréal`.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this functionality exist in Spring Data.

Because you are using PostgreSQL you can use [**unaccent Extension**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html) It can help you in your case, beside you have to create a **native custom query** like this :

**PostgresSQL**

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name "
                                 + "WHERE unaccent(col_name) = unaccent(:name)")
public List<EntityName> find(@Param("name") String name);
```

---

**Note :** you have to Enable this `unaccent` extension in your database :

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

---

**MySQL**

For those who use MySQL you can use `collate utf8_bin` Like this :

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM table_name "
                                 + "WHERE col_name = :name collate utf8_bin")
public List<EntityName> find(@Param("name") String name);
```

---

**SQL Server**

For those who are using Oracle you can use [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx)

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE "
        + "name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like :name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI")
public List<EntityName> find(@Param("name") String name);
```

---

References :

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations)
- [How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-%C3%A8-%C3%A9-%C3%AA-and-%C3%AB-in-sql-ser)

Comment: Really appreciate your example. I succeeded to transform `findAllByNameStartingWithIgnoreCaseOrderByName` to `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.city "
            + "WHERE upper(unaccent(city_name)) LIKE upper(unaccent(:name) || '%')")`.

Comment: Are you familiar with spring batch? I have another question about a JDBC exception skipping in spring batch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263616/spring-batch-error-tolerance).

Comment: @JasminDan I will take a look later, If I have an idea, I will share it with you

Comment: What if you want to limit results using Pageable?

Comment: @Kikin-Sama I will check this when I have some free time :)